# octez-client: Import keys from mnemonic gives a different address

Tags: tezos-client, kukai

I am using octez-client to import keys using a mnemonic phrase:

```
echo -e 'twelve word mnemonic here\npassphrase here\n' | octez-client import keys from mnemonic my_alias -f
```

I have checked that I can import my wallet using the Kukai.app wallet and there I wasn't prompted for a passphrase. Thus I attempted an empty passphrase with octez-client:

```
echo -e 'twelve word mnemonic here\n\n' | octez-client import keys from mnemonic my_alias -f
```

The above command runs and I get some secret keys, but they are for the wrong account and it changes if I try to change the passphrase.

*What am I missing here to make the key import work the same as on Kukai?*

If you happen to know how I can import a `hd-wallet.tez` file to tezos-client that would also be a work-around I could use.

###### Edit

Many thanks. I was helped by the tip of going via Temple wallet which imports the mnemonic and can reveal the unencrypted key. As additional steps, I had to prepend the key with the scheme `unencrypted:edsk`. To finally get the key encrypted and imported to octez-client I ran:

```
octez-client encrypt secret key
 octez-client import secret key my_alias encrypted:edeskEncryptedKeyHere
```

Answer (score 3):

Kukai uses [BIP-32 HD Keys](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). As a workaround, you can export your mnemonic to the Temple Wallet and "Reveal Private Key" there. Or you can use any SDK, working with HD Keys. For instance, you can use [Netezos SDK](https://netezos.dev/docs/wallet-import.html):

```
var hdKey = HDKey.FromMnemonic(new Mnemonic("clarify flash mansion forward turtle dinner drill turkey dry draw kidney brain fruit tiny aspect"));
var childHdKey = hdKey.Derive("m/44'/1729'/0'/0'");
Console.WriteLine($"Private key: {childHdKey.Key.GetBase58()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Address: {childHdKey.Address}");
```

An example at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhgtD4)

Answer (score 1):

A slight correction to the answer above

Kuaki uses Slip10 HD keys for tz1 keys and bip32 HD keys for tz2/3

the reason why octez-client does not return your same account is that it does not return HD keys

your mnemonic does not go through any derivations like in the step
`var childHdKey = hdKey.Derive("m/44'/1729'/0'/0'");`
default for tezos is 44'/1729' and the latter specify which child to derive.

Kukai has derived your child account down to `44'/1729'/0'/0'`

This all being said, the secret key is the fastest way to get your account onto octez-client which can be found in the methods listed in the previous answer.

Temple (to me) would be the fastest way to find your accounts secret key.